# iphone app: cannot retrieve property from a Custom Singleton

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created the following Singleton in my iPhone app:

```
#import "AppManager.h"

static AppManager *sharedAppManager = nil;

@implementation AppManager

@synthesize currentType, listOfTypes;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedAppManager == nil)
            sharedAppManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedAppManager;
 }
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        currentType = @"";
        listOfTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"T1", @"T2", @"T3", nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
    [currentType release];
    [listOfTypes release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

When I use it:

```
// TEST
AppManager *appManager = [AppManager sharedManager];
NSArray *array = appManager.listOfTypes;
NSLog(@"TYPES:%@", array);
```

I have a strange thing...

```
TYPES:<UIButtonContent: 0x7b8db10 Title = (null), Image = <UIImage: 0x7bad7f0>, Background = (null), TitleColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1, ShadowColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0.5>
```

It's working fine with currentType (NSString property) but it does not with listOfTypes (NSArray)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not retaining the array *listOfTypes*, so the array probably got released and  is pointing to some garbage value. Use the following to retain the array (if it is a retained/copied property).

```
self.listOfTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"T1", @"T2", @"T3", nil];
```

You can also simply send the *retain* message to the array.

```
listOfTypes = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"T1", @"T2", @"T3", nil] retain];
```

or allocate the array.

```
listOfTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"T1", @"T2", @"T3", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listOfTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"T1", @"T2", @"T3", nil];
```

This line is allocating an autoreleased array directly to your instance variable. By the time you are accessing it the memory has been reassigned to a different object.

I am assuming your listOfTypes is a retainer property. Either assign is using `self.listOfTypes=` or add a `retain` to the code above.

You aren't seeing this with your other property as you have assigned a static string which doesn't get released.